# What is "redirect_uri" of google colab for youtube api v3 in google console?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-colaboratory, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I want to authorize to my youtube channel from google colab. Now i need redirect uri in google console for create oAuth of youtube API v3.
for example this is url that must use by python in google colab for authorize to my youtube channel:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload&access_type=offline&response_type=code
I must replace my client id in this link but before all of this i must set `redirect_uri` in google console for creating oAuth of google colab. if i not set redirect uri then google console use `localhost` By default and when i run link on browser i will not get any response code and get only empty page at last.
when i use `http://localhost` as redirect uri i get something like this with empty screen on latest page:
http://localhost/?code=4/0AVHEtk7j41Y-tBNEy7jWToXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXz7KipIA4RzNSTnaNXXXXXXX_uQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload

which redirect uri i must for google colab to authorize to my youtube channel?
i want to use following script and need redirect uri for it:
https://github.com/Amagnum/google-drive-to-youtube-video